# XBee Series 2 communication issue -- can't establish network

Tags: xbee

I am facing a problem forming a network between 2 XBee S2 modules.  I suspect that the problem is about the operating channel.  People told me that with Series 2, the channel is chosen automatically but that isn't happening.  I already configured both modules perfectly but the operating channel isn't the same for the two modules.

So my question is: should I connect the 2 XBees at the same time by USB adapter so they can operate on the same channel or what?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try some of Digi International's Getting Started tutorials on their [Digi XBee Examples & Guides](http://examples.digi.com/) site.  My guess is that you're setting up both modules as Coordinator, and you need to have one as Coordinator (to establish the network) and one as Router (to join the Coordinator's network).

Comment: I've seen different possibilities to set the Destination Serial number in each module. I tried the one suggested in the link. But it doesn't work.
What's the correct configuration for the Coordinator and the Router?

Comment: On a two-node network, you can set `DH` and `DL` on each module to match `SH` and `SL` from the other module.  You can use `0` for `DH` and `DL` as a shortcut on the router to refer to the coordinator.

Comment: Your configuration doesn't work for me. Please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26111123/xbee-router-coordinator-configuration-s2) question

Answer (score 0):

Try to upload each module (one as ZBcoordinator and another one as ZBrouter) the coordinator will automaticaly have the address 0x00000000 and the router will always point to coordinator as long it has has same PANID (exp 7EEE)....