# Configuring Xbee S2 with XC-TU

Tags: arduino, wireless, xbee

I'm trying to set up a very basic network using 2 Xbee modules. One as Coordinator and the other as Router.

**The Problem**

I am only able to send data from Arduino (Router) to XCTU (Coordinator). It's a mono directional communication. What's the correct configuration for these modules in order to establish a bidirectional communication?

I have followed these tutorials and none of them worked.

- http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/Zigbee_Networking_with_XBee_Series_2_and_Seeed%27s_Products
- http://www.digi.com/support/forum/40215/how-to-send-data-from-router-to-coordinator-in-api-mode-xbee-s2
- http://xbee.wikispaces.com/Mesh+with+Xbee

The Modem version is **XB24-ZB**. The **coordinator** has 20A7 firmware and the following serial number:

high:13A200 and low: **407B69E6**

The **Router** with firmware 22A7:

high:13A200 and low: *40813BFC*

Here is the Coordinator configuration: ZIGBEE COORDINATOR AT

- PAN ID: 1111
- DH: 13A200
- DL: *40813BFC* (Rooter serial number low)
- Baud Rate: 57600

Here is the Router Configuration: ZIGBEE ROUTER AT

- PAN ID: 1111
- DH: 13A200
- DL: **407B69E6** (Coordinator serial number low)
- Baud Rate: 57600

Comment: I swapped the modules and realized that it's an issue related to wiring. The code is the same I used with the Arduino Uno. Then I changed the board to Arduino Mega and the problem showed up... Thank you TomLogic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you swap the XBee modules, does the problem follow the module or the device (Arduino/XCTU)? You want to determine whether it's an issue with the XBee, or the Arduino. Another thing to try would be connecting both XBee modules to serial ports on a PC with XCTU. If data is bi-directional, then it's an issue with the code or wiring on the Arduino.

Comment: I'm able to send data from the Arduino (Router) to the Computer (coordinator), If I swap the Xbee modules no problem. But I have trouble communicating to the Arduino. I open the terminal tab in XCTU and when I write something the TX and the RSSI leds light up on the Explorer board. Same thing occurs on the Arduino, the DOUT and RSSI led light up and nothing is received. What is the RSSI led?